# JS function - Math optimization, off by 1 in some cases

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, math, mathematical-optimization

I'm still wet behind the ears with web dev, not the best at math, and have problems moving on when something is still broken. Hopefully you guys can help.

Quick: I'm using Jquery to make some (dynamic in number) divs in my header overlap by 30%, filling the entire width of the container. My current iteration rounds up one too many times, so my last element goes beneath the rest.

I have X elements filling the full width of my header container. Each element overlaps by 30% on either side. In an equation, I can work out the math no problem. Ensuring pixel precision with these numbers has proven more difficult. This is what I'm using to determine the width of each element.

```
width of element = [container width] / ((.7 * ([# of elements] - 1)) + 1)
left margin of element = [width of element] * .3
```

I make variables I call extraWidth and extraMargin which are the width and margin % 1 respectively. The default element width I use now is width-(width%1). For every element, I add the extraWidth and extraMargin to running total variables. Any time the total of either of these variables exceeds .5, that particular element has its width or margin set 1 higher than the default.

So I don't run on any longer, [here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4a3vgb4q/3/) with everything necessary to see what I'm dealing with. It runs fine most of the time, but at certain widths I'm 1 pixel too wide.

p.s.

Ran the JSFiddle, didn't work the same way as my live sandbox site, [so check that out here](http://exceptionalish.com). I feel like I included all the necessary bits, but I can't say for sure. On my Chrome, when window size is 575px (among many other widths) it's messed up.

**EDIT**

It should be noted that I'm making changes to my live site without updating this post. I'm not deleting any functions just yet though, just making new ones/minor alterations to existing ones.

Comment: your live site looks like a single line to me - the fiddle is broken though

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm talking about the header portion of the live site, with the circles. Looking into the fiddle... -- EDIT yeah, I set the CSS to show an example of the broken size bit. If you change the CSS for head-Circles to 576px width and run it again, the circles fix just fine.

Comment: as I said, the live site looks fine to me, unlike the fiddle

Comment: @JaromandaX I understand it looks good on these cases, but when it scales down for mobile (like with the window width of 575px), the jquery math breaks by a pixel or two.

Comment: setting widthRem and marginRem to 0 seems to fix it - so, it seems your use of these "remainders" is what is causing the issue - I've not gone through the logic of your maths too much, as this can surely be achievable using pure (modern) css!

Comment: @JaromandaX Made a fork with CSS for 577px width and those variables set to 0 where it breaks again. https://jsfiddle.net/ej3fzLLq/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ej3fzLLq/2/ - no fancy maths in this :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Ahhh, either I was unclear or you missed one of the key parts of my question. These circles need to fill the ENTIRE width of my container. It's my header. I may have other contents or borders filling my content rail, and it would look awkward and silly to have a header that only stretches most of the way across your content section.

Comment: I totally feel like I should have just been using percentages... So I'll just be on my way to try that out.

Comment: I think adjustment in `circleMargin` is problem. The rounding off should be in other way. Meaning it should be rounded to upper integer.

Comment: FYI: for future reference - take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/rccdonau/ - horizontally resize the output panel - no JS required :p

Comment: @JaromandaX I DID forget about the vh/vw measurements, though because I expect my header circle elements to be generated dynamically in the future, I need to use SOME sort of scripting to get the width, height, and margin right. This certainly makes the JS potentially WAY easier though, so thank you! I do try to avoid things like calc() in my css though because my current job has to follow certain standards for accessibility.

Comment: Sure, I understand - though the code can still be simplified if you can use `calc` - https://jsfiddle.net/rccdonau/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion! Recursion was the most elegant answer (which appears to work in ALL cases) I could come up with.

Iterating through my jQuery object one element at a time and calculating the width and margin based on the remaining container width rather than the whole container width makes this much easier to calculate.

```
function circleWidth(circles, containerWidth) {
    var width = containerWidth / ((.7 * (circles.length - 1)) + 1);
    var pxWidth = Math.round(width);
    var margin = width * .3;
    var pxMargin = Math.round(margin);

    $(circles[0]).css({
        'width': pxWidth + "px",
        'margin-left': "-" + pxMargin + "px"
    });

    containerWidth -= (pxWidth - pxMargin);

    if (circles.length > 1) {
        circleWidth(circles.slice(1), containerWidth);
    }
}

function circleSize(circles, containerWidth) {
    var height = Math.ceil(containerWidth / ((.7 * (circles.length - 1)) + 1));

    circles.each(function() {
        $(this).css({
            'height': height + "px"
        });
    });

    circleWidth(circles, containerWidth);

    $(circles[circles.length]).css({
        'margin-left': $(circles[0]).css('margin-left')
    });

    $(circles[0]).css({
        'margin-left': 0
    });
}
```

[Here's the fiddle with my final result](https://jsfiddle.net/5rczrv27/1/). I'm sure I still have some optimization to do, but at least it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices:

Calculate `pixelMargin` as next integer. like:

```
var pixelMargin = Math.ceil(circleMargin);
```

or you can use `pixelMargin` in %.

1st one worked for me.